# Android BroadcastReceiver executes twice more

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

So I have 2 bluetooth GATT server objects of the same class. 
Each of them has a IntentFilter and BroadcastReceiver.
As the object receives data from Bluetooth server, it executes specific function in BroadcastReceiver.

Unfortunately if I send two requests (one from each object) the response executes four times.
As I understood that response due to first request executes in BroadcastReceiver of both object and then again response from second object request executes in both objects.

How do I specify, that the BroadcastReceiver executes code only in the object the request came from?

Comment: Improve your question with some code excerpts. That would be better to help you.

Comment: There is not much code. As I said. 2 object - in each of them there are filters and receiver. That's it.

Comment: I get the same thing with BT where it disconnects and I get two notifications.

Comment: iam having same problem in some other case my reciever is invoking two times

Answer (score 0):

If the call to `sendBroadcast()` and the `BroadcastReceiver` are both inside of the same object, I have to wonder if using broadcasts at all is really a good approach (but without code, that's an assumption).

To directly answer your question, though, you must use one of the filterable parameters of an `Intent` to differentiate the two.  For instance, if they have the same action, set a different `Uri` in the data field, or a different MIME type parameter specific to each object.  Then, when you register the receivers with your `IntentFilter` apply those specific parameters from the object to the filter.